# Creating views in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm writing a code at the moment that has to access a transactions file multiple times for a given date range. I was wondering if it's possible to set up a "view" of my table to allow a single delete from at the start of the code (without affecting the table underneath) so that the date range will always be applied throughout the code

So in a simplified example changing the code from...

```
SELECT    SUM(sales)  
FROM      trans_file
WHERE     date_field BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-31'
```

To this...

```
DELETE
FROM    trans_file
WHERE   date_field NOT BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-31'

SELECT    SUM(sales)  
FROM      trans_file
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to perform a [Deep Copy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/performing-a-deep-copy.html) first,
access data multiple times and then delete the "view", like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE trans_file_view AS (
    SELECT * FROM trans_file 
    WHERE date_field BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-31'
);

SELECT SUM(sales) FROM trans_file_view;
...next SELECT statements...

DROP TABLE trans_file_view;
```

**Bibliography:**
You can read more about [Deep Copy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/performing-a-deep-copy.html)